# Sending email using custom template and using TriggeredSend

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, .net

I created a template in Exact Target account. How do I send an email by referencing template I created and using TriggeredSend object function from SOAP API (in .NET) ?

Just to add, How to associate template to Email using SOAP API.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggered sending requires you to set up an interaction prior to sending.  Each interaction would require you to assign the template, and "start" the interaction prior to using.  Updating the template would require you to stop and restart the interaction.

For more information regarding triggered sending, I would review the [Triggered Send Scenario for Developers](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/triggered_email_scenario_guide_for_developers/).  This should help you have a full understanding of how the entire process works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use API calls also to associate an existing Triggered Send Definition with a custom Email Template. [Check out this.](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/submitting_a_triggered_send_definition_using_the_asynchronous_api/)

Another way, you can

1. pause
2. update TSD with new Template association
3. publish
4. Lastly, start the an existing Triggered Send Definition

Links:  [Update TSD](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/starting_a_triggered_send_definition_via_the_web_service_api/)